# Sometimes, after grub, ubuntu boots to purple screen then black screen

Tags: boot, 16.04

After grub I get purple screen for a minute then black screen for ever.

When I say black screen, I mean totally black, no command line.

Fortunately it happens only sometimes and when I reboot with power button it boots normally.

I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but nothing happens.

I found some people with the same problem:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157067

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/19d0kl/when_booting_ubuntu_1204_i_just_get_a_purple/

https://forum.teksyndicate.com/t/solved-ubuntu-14-04-black-screen/75033/29

Comment: Have you noticed any patterns as to when that happens?

Comment: I didn't, but I will pay more attention if something is said on command line before black screen comes and I will post here. I'm sure that more people have this problem too. As I can't identify the error after it occurs because the screen turns black, it's difficult to diagnose. It can be a hardware or ubuntu problem. When it's with HD normally it boots to intframs, so It's something with ubuntu or graphic card I guess.

Comment: What do you see before the black screen ? Do you have an external graphics card ?! This could be a graphics card malfunction Edit: Not specifically the card it self.. the driver could be not working properly

Comment: @kbhsas I don't have external graphic card. Maybe the driver is not working ok, but why sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't?